# Can I create an $http request and not submitting it (yet)?

Tags: angularjs

I have a generic component in my system that deals with submitting HTTP requests in chunks. It takes care of some application-common headers that I need to attach and updating all the necessary places in the GUI.

This component is shared between couple other components for various use-cases. I'm trying to delegate the task of creating HTTP request from a given input to the callers but found out that when the caller does:

```
var req = $http.get("url", {})
```

It's already submitting the request.

I'd like the callers to provide a method to generate a list of request objects from the input, and my component will deal with that later (add some headers for example, add `success()` and `error()` methods, or submit the requests in batches).

How can I only create the HTTP Request object, without sending it?

Comment: `var config = {method: 'GET', url: 'http://foo.com'};` Store this config object somewhere, and when ready to send the request, use `$http(config)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create wrapper function for "delayed" http request, that would return you preconfigured ready to call function, and use it instead of `$http`.

Maybe like this:

```
function dHttp(config) {
    return function(options) {
       angular.merge(config, options);
       return $http(config);
    }
}

var req = dHttp({
    url: '/some', 
    data: {test: 21}
});

// later send it
req().then(function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks. what if I later need to change the request? (add headers for example)

Answer (score 0):

A plain AJAX can be useful here

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","a-url",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

`$http.get()` is a declarative form of an ajax open and send.

```
var reqArr = [];
reqArr.push(xmlhttp.open("GET","a-url",true));
reqArr.push(xmlhttp.open("GET","b-url",true));
reqArr.push(xmlhttp.open("GET","c-url",true));
```

so you can change the objects as needed and send the ajax later on.